# Implicit intent from test application

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new for implicit intent part of android.

In my application I have registered the intent like below:

```
<activity
    android:name="ihpc.mocha.fakertt.view.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape" >

    <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        <data
            android:host="mocha"
            android:path="/RTT/reset"
            android:scheme="content" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
<activity
    android:name="ihpc.mocha.fakertt.view.SessionTimeOutActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape" >

    <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data
            android:host="mocha"
            android:path="/RTT/sessionTimeOut"
            android:scheme="content" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Now I want to trigger these intent from some test application but I do not know how to achieve that? I tried googling the same but could not find appropriate solution.Please suggest the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

your intent filter will catch all the intent with the "android.intent.action.VIEW" key. so if any application send an intent with this your application will receive. To test from another test application try this

```
intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
// if needed put some extra data
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: That means If I call this code from any other app then my SessionTimeOutActivity will be called?

Comment: normally it does in this way. But i never tried to call an implicit intent from a test activity to test another. You tell after experimenting

Comment: It is showing a list but that list does not have my application :(